# Why im getting 0 all the time when using indexOf?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
for (int i = 0; i < links.Count; i++)
{
    int f = links[i].IndexOf("http");
}
```

`links` is `List<string>`
For example in index 0 I have: `http://test/107281.shtml#34`
I want to extract from this link only this:
`http://test/107281.shtml` without the #34 in the end.

But for the start why f return 0 all the time ?

Comment: Well you're looking for the first occurrence of `http` in the string. If all the strings start with `http`, why would it ever return anything other than 0? Perhaps you should be using `IndexOf("#")` instead?

Comment: Because firs occurrence of `http` in `http://test/107281.shtml` at `0` index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first char in a string is located at index 0, so in the string `http://test/107281.shtml#34` as `http` is the first thing in the string its located at index 0...
To extract you can use either regex or `indexOf("#")` in combination with `substring`.

Answer (score 3):

It's right...., cause this string "http" start index is 0, if couldn't found string, IndexOf will return -1...

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < links.Count; i++)
{
    int f = links[i].IndexOf("#");
}
```

This should give you the index of the first `#`.
[`IndexOf("http")`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8b1470s.aspx) should give you `0` as `http` is at index `0`.
To get the string you are seeking:

```
for (int i = 0; i < links.Count; i++)
{
    var url = links[i].Substring(0, links[i].IndexOf("#"));
}
```

Example using your demo string [HERE](https://dotnetfiddle.net/lrERpx).

Answer (score 0):

The indexOf() method returns the position of the first occurrence of a specified value in a string.

```
var str = "Hello world, welcome to the universe.";
var n = str.indexOf("welcome");
```

Output wil be : 13 
which is the position number.

Next you remove from which position you want to delete.

Answer (score 0):

```
        List<string> link_list = new List<string> { "http://test/107281.shtml#34", "http://test/107281.shtml#35" };
        List<string> new_list = new List<string>();
        foreach (var item in link_list)
        {
            string bb = item.Substring(0, item.ToString().IndexOf("#"));
            new_list.Add(bb);
        }
```